# Replace mustache placeholders in text with conditional values based on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, mustache

I need to change the values from the variable $v_file recursively. For that I created a recursive function that loops through my array $arr and substitutes the placeholders with the values from my array.

```php
function replace_file($arr, $v_file){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {  
        if (is_array($value)) {
            replace_file($value, $v_file);
        }else{
            if($value == "check"){echo("$key ||| $value <br/>");
                $v_file = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', 'check-square.svg', $v_file);
            }elseif ($value == "uncheck") {
                $v_file = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', 'square.svg', $v_file);
            }else{
                $v_file = str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $value, $v_file);
            }
        }
    }
    return $v_file;
}
```

Here is the array I'm trying to loop through

```php
Array ( 
    [nomec] => john doe 
    [pessoac] => 1234 
    [datanascc] => 01/01/0001 
    [cpfcnpjc] => 999.999.999-99 
    [rgc] => 99.999.999-9 
    [proposta] => Array ( 
        [inclusao] => check 
        [exclusao] => uncheck 
        [alteracaodados] => uncheck 
        [segviacartao] => uncheck 
    ) 
    [beneficiario] => Array ( 
        [titular] => check 
        [dependente] => uncheck 
        [agregado] => check 
    ) 
)
```

And this is the info I'm trying to substitute with the values from the array:

```php
$file = "{{nomec}}, 
         {{pessoac}}, 
         {{datanascc}}, 
         {{cpfcnpjc}}, 
         {{rgc}}, 
         {{inclusao}}, 
         {{exclusao}},
         {{alteracaodados}}, 
         {{segviacartao}}, 
         {{titular}}, 
         {{dependente}}, 
         {{agregado}}";
```

When I call the function with `replace_file($obj, $file);` and print the result, I get:

`john doe, 1234, 01/01/0001, 999.999.999-99, 99.999.999-9, {{inclusao}}, {{exclusao}}, {{alteracaodados}}, {{segviacartao}}, {{titular}}, {{dependente}}, {{agregado}}`

Comment: The name of the function in the recursive call is not the same. Is that just a typo in the question here?

Comment: Also, remember PHP passes by value, so the result of the recursive call will need to be reassigned for it to have any effect.

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic! Yes, just a typo!
Where can i reassign the result?

Comment: In the recursive call: `$v_file = replace_file($value, $v_file);`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have no need for the first level keys when there is a second level of data.

You can avoid MUCH of that inefficient and convoluted recursive function by building a translation array (albeit using recursion -- but a native recursive call).  Then `strtr()` will do the magical part of replacing strings after keys are wrapped in doubled curly braces and values are conditionally assigned.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OdCOO))

```
$trans = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($v, $k) use (&$trans) {
        $trans["{{{$k}}}"] = match($v) {
            'check' => 'check-square.svg',
            'uncheck' => 'square.svg',
            default => $v
        };
    }
);
echo strtr($file, $trans);
```